# Laravel Eloquent get all Posts stored in categories with Roles

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have four tables in a database named: `Category`, `User`, `Role` and then `Post`. In the `Category` table I have a column `category_id` which by this column i can have multiple child in category.

Every `user` belongsToMany `roles` and `categories` and each `category` belongsToMany `posts`, **i must get all posts by `role` which logged into our application**

As you can see in below screen shot `manager 1` and `manager 2` belongsToMany `programings`, `dart`, `flutter` and `php`.

[image]

you can suppose `manager 1` user id is `1` and `manager 2` is `2` and both of them are `manager` role

my question is how can i get all posts which *logged user* belongsToMany `categories` by `role`

logged user is `manager 1` and i want to get all posts which saved into categories from parent which that's `PROGRAMINGS`

for example:

```php
$categories = Category::whereNull('category_id')->whereHas('users.roles', function($q){
    return $q->whereLabel('is-manager');
})->with(['posts' => function ($query) {
    $query->with('language');
}])->get();
dd($categories->pluck('posts'));
```

## NOTE:

with @Med.ZAIRI answer which posted on this thread every user in `MANAGER 2` which is't synced into `MANAGER 1`, can see all of `MANAGER 1` posts

> In the Model Category add a relationship, like:

```
/**
* this will get the parent category
*/
public function parentCategory()
{
    return $this->belongsTo( Category::class, 'category_id', 'id' );
}
```

> Then, try to get Posts with their categories and their parent
> Categories, and the users with their Roles, like:

```
$posts = Post::with( ['category.parentCategory', 'user.roles'])->get()
```

## my used models in this senario:

```php
class Category extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    protected $hidden = ['id', 'category_id'];

    public function parentCategory()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo( Category::class, 'category_id', 'id' );
    }

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class);
    }

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
    }

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class);
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }

    public function childrenCategories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class)->with('categories');
    }
}


class Role extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }

    public function permission()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class);
    }

    public function hasPermission($permission)
    {
        return !!$permission->intersect($this->roles->permission)->count();
    }
}


class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable, SoftDeletes, UsersOnlineTrait;

    protected $guarded = [
        'id',
    ];
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
        'avatar_path' => 'array',
        'experiences' => 'array',
    ];

    public function group()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(UserGroup::class, 'user_user_group');
    }

    public function child()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class)->with('child');
    }

    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }

    public function properties()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(UsersProperty::class);
    }

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
    }

    public function hasRole($role)
    {
        return $this->roles->contains('id', $role);
        /*if (is_string($role)) {
        } else {
            return !!$role->intersect($this->roles)->count();
        }*/
    }

    public function hasRoleByName($role)
    {
        if ($role == null) return false;
        if (is_string($role)) {
            return $this->roles->contains('name', $role) || $this->roles->contains('label', $role);
        } else {
            return !!$role->intersect($this->roles)->count();
        }
    }

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you post the database schema ( like the picture in the question)?

Comment: @Med.ZAIRI i updated post, is it enough ?

Comment: I saw, thank you. could you tell me what is the relation between the Role and the Category?

Comment: @Med.ZAIRI i dont have any relation-ship between `category` and `role`, i sync users into roles and then for each category OR parent of multiple category i sync user(s)

Comment: That's good, I could say that you need to get all Categories with their posts for the connected user, is that right?

Comment: @Med.ZAIRI logged user maybe doesn't have any post and only can get all posts which that belongs to parent category with children, like with blog administrator, blog administrator can manages posts without having any post, then i should get all posts with user belongs to that and their post BY ROLE

Comment: Can you post a DB schema? Or let me know if I understand it correctly:

Users have many Roles.
Users have many Categories (interested in).
Posts have many Categories.

You want all posts in which the user is interested (based on which category he follows) + the posts of sub-categories as well?

Comment: @whyguy you can download nessessary db schema from this link: `https://upinja.com/up1/my-db.zip`, let me describe what happen, `Users` have many `Roles`, we sync `users` into many categories, `NOT ROLES`. each `Category` have many `Posts`, now  with this scenario users specified in roles, we want to get categories with, which users in this category, i'm not sure this db-schema is correct,

Comment: @DolDurma please add some seeds data and export DB again

Comment: @whyguy please download from here `https://gofile.io/d/uVj9VJ`

Comment: @whyguy i'm so sorry,i had forgotten my native language is not English, would you want to wait me to seed another data?

Comment: @DolDurma Can you please provide some seed data in English?

Comment: @Donkarnash yes, sure. let me to send file

Comment: @DolDurma Awaiting the seed data (in English) file - just a reminder

Comment: @Donkarnash sorry late answer, i uploaded, `https://gofile.io/d/QtRGkX` in that `ella Jackson` is owner of `web` category with all of their sub-directories and shouldn't see articles which posted into `mobile` category with all of their sub-directories  which `scarlett Lincoln` is owner

Comment: @whyguy please see above comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trait with methods to get all available posts for the logged in user
based on the role

```php
class User extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable, HasPosts;
}



<?php

namespace App\Concerns;

use App\Models\Category;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

trait HasPosts
{
    /**
     * Get all available posts for the currently logged in user
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function posts()
    {
        $method = 'postsFor' . Str::studly(str_replace('is-', '', $this->roles->first()->label));

        return $this->{$method}()->collapse();
    }

    /**
     * Get all posts associated with all categories including
     * their subcategories for the logged in Portal Manager
     */
    public function postsForPortalManager(): Collection
    {
        return Category::with([
            'subcategories.posts.language', 
            'posts.language'
        ])
        ->get()
        ->pluck('posts');
    }

    /**
     * Get all posts for the logged in Manager which belong to
     * one of the categories associated with the Manager
     */
    public function postsForManager(): Collection
    {
        return $this->categories()
            ->with('posts.language')
            ->get()
            ->pluck('posts')
            ->filter(function ($collection) {
                return !!$collection->count();
            });
    }

    /**
     * Get only the posts which belong to the categories for the Editor
     * and which are authored by the logged in Editor
     */
    public function postsForEditor(): Collection
    {
        return $this->categories()
            ->with([
                'posts' => function ($query) {
                    $query->where('user_id', $this->id)->with('language');
                }, 
                'posts.language'
            ])
            ->get()
            ->pluck('posts')
            ->filter(function ($collection) {
                return !!$collection->count();
            });
    }

    /**
     * Get only the posts which belong to the categories for the Writer
     * and which are authored by the logged in Writer
     */
    public function postsForWriter(): Collection
    {
        return $this->categories()
            ->with([
                'posts' => function ($query) {
                    $query->where('user_id', $this->id)->with('language');
                }, 
                'posts.language'
            ])
            ->get()
            ->pluck('posts')
            ->filter(function ($collection) {
                return !!$collection->count();
            });
    }
}
```

Then for any authenticated user we can fetch available posts with

```
$user->posts()
```

It works with the seed data you have provided.

ella is not able to see the post on Flutter and scarlett is not able to see the post on laravel

Only assumption here is that have taken the first role of the authenticated user to lookup the method used.

Comment: i'm wondering why i get incorrect result. can i accept your post to let me implementing simple project into `github`?

Comment: Sure will upload a repo to github and post the link soon

Comment: Thanks, let me to create repository in Github.com

Comment: @DolDurma https://github.com/neeravp/doldurma is the repository link. On the welcome page there are two links one for posts for user Ella and Scarlett each.

Comment: Thank you very much, let me check, if thats need to update wait me to pull request

Comment: hi. Can I have your email address?

Comment: @Donkarmash thanks, you can delete your comment now

Answer (score 1):

In the Model Category add a relationship, like:

```
/**
* this will get the parent category
*/
public function parentCategory()
{
    return $this->belongsTo( Category::class, 'category_id', 'id' );
}
```

Then, try to get Posts with their categories and their parent Categories, and the users with their Roles, like:

```
$posts = Post::with( ['category.parentCategory', 'user.roles'])->get()
```

Comment: i found a simple issue, with your query implementation user which is into `MANAGER 2` can see all of `MANAGER 1` category posts and this is not correct because user doesnt' sync in `MANAGER 1` category

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your roles model:

```
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class);
    }
```

After that you can reach posts from the user, like:

```
$authorizedUser->roles()->with('categories.posts')->get();
```

You can flatten the result to access posts directly as well

Comment: `categories` synced with `users` not `roles`

Answer (score 0):

If your relationships are all many-to-many as below:

`roles  >-<  users  >-<  categories  >-<  posts`

and are all defined properly in the models, e.g.

```php
// Role.php
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}

// User.php
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
}

// Category.php
public function posts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class);
}
```

then I'm pretty sure you should be able to do

```php
$role = Role::find(1);

// get all posts from all categories from all users with $role
$posts = $role->users()->categories()->posts;
```

Comment: i have relation ships in my models but i get this error: ` Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::categories()`